# Highchart ASP .NET MVC ось x как метка времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Не добавлении точек, не строится шкала времени по оси х.

Код контроллера:

```
public ActionResult GetChartData()
        {
            var data = new List<SensorSeries>();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    data.Add(new SensorSeries(DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString(), rnd.Next()));
                }
            }
            con.Close();

            var dataforchart = data.Select(x => new { date = x.Timestamp, y = x.Value });

            return Json(dataforchart, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Код представления:

```
@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/Charts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document)
    .ready(function () {

        $('#chartbtn')
            .click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        var series = [
                            {
                                type: 'area',
                                name: 'Some series',
                                data: data
                            }
                        ];

                        createChart("#chartArea", "Sample line", series);
                    }
                });
            });
    });

    function createChart(chartcontainer, title, series) {

        $(chartcontainer)
            .highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: {
                                x1: 0,
                                y1: 0,
                                x2: 0,
                                y2: 1
                            },
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },
                series: series,
                title: {
                    text: title
                }
            });
    }
```

Скриншот построенного графика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в смысле не строится? а что мы на графике видим, как не шкалу времени?

Comment: Шкала отображается по умолчанию как настроена. Метки времени для каждой точки инициализируются в строке data.Add(new SensorSeries(DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString(), rnd.Next()));
Соответственно если бы оно корректно работало, то хотя бы текущую дату на оси отображало. А так непонятно что

Comment: дата у вас в самом начале шкалы `1 января` написано, а дальше временные метки с интервалом `100мс`. Видимо таков стандартный формат представления? Что по факту у вас в HTML коде то за данные передаются в чарты? То есть JSON-ответ сервера то что содержит?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Таймштамп нужно передавать в формате тиков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Во-первых: данные для обработки джава скриптом нужно передавать в тиках (вот в таком виде 1505384123586), поэтому я набросал маленькую функцию которая принимает время и возвращает тики.

```
public static long GetJavascriptTimestamp(DateTime input)
    {
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Parse("1/1/1970").Ticks);
        DateTime time = input.Subtract(span);
        return (time.Ticks / 10000);
    }
```

Далее заполняю коллекцию данными и передаю всё это добро в представление через JSON.
Еще есть нюанс в Highcharts с которым я долго провозился. По умолчанию, максимальное количество точек в серии 1000. Для расширения этого значения и оптимизации производительности нужно явно указать параметр в настройках серии turboThreshold: (Максимальное кол-во точек).